# attribute selector issue

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm applying a class on all the select boxes.

```
$('select[class!="skip_these"]').uniform();
```

and the above code means when I apply to any select box with class `skip_there` it will not be applied and it works.

```
<select name="xyz" class="skip_these"></select>
```

But when I add another class it applies and I don't want that.

```
<select name="xyz" class="skip_these myclass"></select>
```

Is there a way to resolve it?
I don't want to change the plugin for this.

Can it be done by jQuery selector?

Comment: if(object.hasClass("")) dont do what it does when it doesn´t have it else do it

Comment: +1, good question. Problem with `class!=skip_these` is that you are literally checking the whole value of `class` not being `skip_these` which off course is not true if another class is added. As the answers showed, using the opposite approach looking for what is `not` present instead works well. Again, good question and definitely useful to future users.

Comment: It's a good question in that there doesn't appear to be a duplicate.  For future reference the OP could have quickly got the answer by googling "_jQuery not contains selector_".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('select:not(.skip_these)').uniform();
```

This will work too:

```
 $('select').not('.skip_these').uniform();
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped, but if not me, somebody other would help in few seconds, so i don't feel to be hero :D

Answer (score 6):

Use the `:not` pseudo-selector:

```
$('select:not(.skip_these)').uniform();
```